# pycharm 2022.2.3 cannot set memory

Tags: pycharm

Re-running the program is particularly slow, I have added the path environment variable in the configuration I guess it is a memory problem.
But no matter what, the memory size cannot be changed.

```
-server
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot,trieDescend
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Dsun.java2d.metal=true
-Djbr.catch.SIGABRT=true
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
```

> D:\PyCharm 2022.2.3\bin\pycharm64.exe.vmoptions
> C:\Users\11507\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2022.2\pycharm64.exe.vmoptions

My pycharm installation is on another disk, I modified pycharm64.exe.vmoptions in two places, and no change after reboot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Configuration file in this address  javaagent:D:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2.3\ja-netfilter-all-main\ja-netfilter.jar=jetbrains

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).